# Get part of the text from RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this. I am trying to get text between several characters before caret and the caret."comparable" is never longer than the actual text in the `RichTextBox`.

This is the code that I have:

```
int coLen = comparable.Length;
TextPointer caretBack = rtb.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(coLen, 
    LogicalDirection.Backward);
TextRange rtbText = new TextRange(caretBack, rtb.CaretPosition);
string text = rtbText.Text;
```

This returns `text = ""`

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works as expected , I get `I a`

Piece of code :

```
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        rtb.AppendText("I am adding some texts to the richTextBox");
        rtb.CaretPosition = rtb.CaretPosition.DocumentEnd;

        int coLen = 3;
        TextPointer caretBack = rtb.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(-coLen);
        TextRange rtbText = new TextRange(caretBack, rtb.CaretPosition);
        string ttt = rtbText.Text;
```

**EDIT**

Here is an MSTest method to explain the behavior of the Caret and reading :

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void TestRichtTextBox()
    {
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        rtb.AppendText("I am adding some texts to the richTextBox");

        int offset = 3;

        TextPointer beginningPointer = rtb.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(offset);
        TextPointer endPointer = rtb.CaretPosition.DocumentEnd;
        TextRange rtbText = new TextRange(beginningPointer, endPointer);

        Assert.IsTrue(rtbText.Text == "m adding some texts to the richTextBox\r\n");

        // Now we if we keep the same beggining offset but we change the end Offset to go backwards.

        beginningPointer = rtb.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(3);
        endPointer = rtb.CaretPosition; // this one is the beginning of the text
        rtbText = new TextRange(beginningPointer, endPointer);
        Assert.IsTrue(rtbText.Text == "I a");

        // Nowe we want to read from the back three characters.
        // so we set the end Point to DocumentEnd.

        rtb.CaretPosition = rtb.CaretPosition.DocumentEnd;
        beginningPointer = rtb.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(-offset);
        endPointer = rtb.CaretPosition; // we already set this one to the end document
        rtbText = new TextRange(beginningPointer, endPointer);
        Assert.IsTrue(rtbText.Text == "Box");
    }
```

Plus here is a comment from MSDN about the negative index :

> offset Type: System.Int32 An offset, in symbols, for which to
>   calculate and return the position. If the offset is negative, the
>   position is calculated in the logical direction opposite of that
>   indicated by the LogicalDirection property.

Comment: Thanks for input.I should be getting "Box"  since I want it to count backwords from the end where the caret is. I want it to get text before caret

Comment: Check my edit, you need to set the CaretPosition to endDocument if you want to go backward and It seems that putting Backward doesn't help, but doing -coLen helps.

Comment: Since I spent so much time working on this can you please explain why and how does this work. Thanks a lot again

Comment: Ok check the edit with this small test method to explain what's happening :)